# issue while navigating through https protected sites

Tags: javascript, html, https

I am login into  a URL say

<https://test.ur>/hix using **https**

Now when I am navigating to other page clicking a link Nothing is getting loaded in the chrome browser and I am getting below exception in the chrome browser console

I am getting an issue like

```
The page at '<<https://test.ur>>/hix/account/signup' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://test.ur/hix/entity/locateassister/locateassistancety…%22%2C%22Yuchi%22%2C%22Yuma%22%2C%22Yupik%22%2C%22Yurok%22%2C%22Zuni%22%5D': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

I am using spring in all of my application and using relative URL to navigate.

Also on this portal on whichever page I navigate I get

GET https://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/robotoslab/v3/y7lebkjgREBJK96VQi37ZobN6UDyHWBl620a-IRfuBk.woff net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

in the browser console

Comment: It's not related to Java.

Answer (score 1):

When you're on an HTTP page, it's insecure to call HTTP content (to get JS, image or in iFrame).
Some browsers (and some versions) will block these contents. Some others will show you a message to inform you.

**Solutions**

**First:** What you can delocate all your HTTP resources into HTTPS (if possible).

**Second:** If the resources are on the same server as the one who serves the page, you can also load resources with relative path and not with absolute path. Or you can do a protocol relative path. For example, instead of

```
<img src="https://localhost:8080/img/logo.png" />
```

You will write

```
<img src="//localhost:8080/img/logo.png" />
```